# Creating symlinks between two files from third directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory structure as follow and my current working directory is "`a`".

```
-->cd a/
-->tree
.
└── b
    └── c
        └── d
            └── e
                └── foo

5 directories, 0 files
```

From directory `a`, which means my current directory is `a`.  I want to create symlink of file `b/c/d/e/foo` to `b/c/d/e/bar`. So that when someone open `b/c/d/e/bar`, contents of `b/c/d/e/foo` will show up.

I tried following but it do not work, it means bar is pointing to `b/c/d/f/foo` from current directory which is an invalid path.

```
-->ln -sf b/c/d/e/foo b/c/d/e/bar

-->tree
.
└── b
    └── c
        └── d
            └── e
                ├── bar -> b/c/d/e/foo
                └── foo

5 directories, 1 file
```

One dirty solution is to `cd` to `b/c/d/e` dir and perform `ln -s`. but I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: Surely that should be `-> b/c/d/e/foo`?

Comment: I want to set  `bar -> foo`  from `a`  directory

Comment: In the `tree` output, you display the symlink as pointing to `b/c/d/f/foo` where the `/f/` can't really be correct.

Comment: @tripleee , you are correct. it was typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `ln -s` is just a piece of text. If you put `ln -s a/b/c d/e` then `d/e`  will point to `d/a/b/c` because `a/b/c` is now the target of the symlink `e` in the directory `d`.

So in your case, simply do

```
ln -s foo b/c/d/e/bar
```

Comment: Note that this creates a *relative* symlink; if you move the link to a new directory, it'll point to "foo" in whatever directory you moved it to. You can also create *absolute* symlinks by using an absolute path in the command (e.g. `ln -s /full/path/to/a/b/c/d/e/foo b/c/d/e/bar`), which will always point to that same absolute path.